# Sliding-Scale Variable Cost Calculator Program (for coffee costs)

Tags: python

Depending on how many pounds of coffee the user is buying it changes the price he pays per pound. Not sure if my logic is correct.

```
def main ():

    lb = int(input('How many Pounds of Coffee ?'))

    coffee1 = lb * 12
    coffee2 = lb * 10
    coffee3 = lb * 8.75
    coffee4 = lb * 7.50

    if lb == 1 <=10:
        print('Your total is $ ',coffee1)
    else: lb == 11 <=20
    print('Your total is $ ',coffee2)


main()
```

Comment: I'm assuming Python 3 by your `print` function calls, can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes python running python 3

Comment: And the colon is in the wrong place on your `else`.

Comment: You haven't specified what this code is supposed to do. How are we to know whether this code is correct, any more than you?

Comment: @200_success I'd argue that they vaguely specify what it's supposed to do, but even that is flimsy at best (as noted by the first section in my review).  Thanks for the close vote, feel free to reject my edit if you haven't already.

Comment: @ThomasWard As your answer shows, the code is almost certainly broken, and thus off-topic anyway.

Comment: @200_success I agree, but i was only saying that for the sake of argument.  Not for a response :)

Answer (score 2):

**It's unclear what exactly you want to accomplish here, if only because you have a handful of unused values that you just *happened* to declare even though you don't need them yet.**

Because your specific case is ***not well defined***, the entire review here is based on my assumptions.  Please make a note that you ***must*** define what your actual problem is first, what your approach should be, and ***then*** you write this code.

As a recommendation for next time, please describe in far more detail what your original problem your program was meant to handle or solve is, and give us those details along with your program.  As it stands, your code and problem case are ambiguous so we can't give you a fully-valid review, not without making ***heavy*** assumptions about what your core problem was.

---

---

> All information after this point is based 100% off of assumptions.  You need to define your actual goals first before writing a program, so these assumptions are based on my interpretation of what your ultimate "end goal" would be, and is not entirely reflective of what your actual aims were.

You define four separate prices for coffee.  You only output two values.  Which means that you're left with two unused values, which is not a good thing.  Why define something if you aren't using it?

It's also unclear what your scale is for the other two prices, but I'm *assuming* that you want to operate on a sliding scale like this, with `lbs_of_coffee` holding the interpreted input, based on my analysis of what you have so far:

- `0 <= lbs_of_coffee <= 10`: $12/pound
- `11 <= lbs_of_coffee <= 20`: $10/pound
- `21 <= lbs_of_coffee <= 30`: $8.75/pound
- `lbs_of_coffee >= 31`: $7.50/pound

If this is the case, we can redo your code to be a bit more readable.  We also don't really have to *store* all the values, we can calculate them on the fly, which makes things a little easier to work with.

---

***ASSUMING that we're working with a sliding scale like above, I have the following suggestions***...

---

**Variables**

`lbs`, while able to be interpreted by those of us not using the Metric system as "pounds", is a little vague, so let's name it `pounds_of_coffee` instead.

---

**You are storing values unnecessarily**

We don't need to calculate the prices and then output them.  Instead, we can calculate the cost on the fly with logic instead:

```
if 0 <= pounds_of_coffee <= 10:
    cost = pounds_of_coffee * 12
elif 11 <= pounds_of_coffee <= 20:
    cost = pounds_of_coffee * 10
elif 21 <= pounds_of_coffee <= 30:
    cost = round(pounds_of_coffee * 8.75, 2)
elif 31 <= pounds_of_coffee:
    cost = round(pounds_of_coffee * 7.50, 2)
else:
    print("You should only be inputting positive, non-zero numbers for the number of pounds of coffee.")
    exit(1)  # Non-zero exit code indicates a non-successful exit.
```

We'll use `cost` later on here.  But keep in mind the use of an error here - if a user inputs something that is not valid, they should get some kind of error response.

---

**Validating Input**

If I wanted to break your program, then when I am prompted for input, I can just put non-numbers in.  This results in a `ValueError` being raised.  We also have this issue if they try and input a decimal, or if they try to enter a negative number.  So let's handle validation of that (building off the above recommendations), and making sure a number was actually entered.  Note that we have to first convert to a `float` in the case of someone putting decimal values in or negative numbers in, *then* convert to an `int`:

```
try:
    pounds_of_coffee = int(float(input('How many Pounds of Coffee ?')))
except ValueError:
    print("You have not entered a valid number, please only enter a valid number.")
    exit(1)  # Non-zero exit code indicates a non-successful exit.
```

---

**Wait, how do we print the actual cost?**

Well, we just need one print statement before the end of the `main` function call:

```
print("Your total cost is: $%d" % cost)
```

---

With the above recommendations, your program ends up looking something like this.  You can test this over at [repl.it](https://repl.it/NXUO/1), just hit the 'Continue as Anonymous' link on the popup if they ask you to register, and you can see this in-action, complete with how it'd show on the terminal at run-time so you can experiment with this code:

```
def main():
    try:
        pounds_of_coffee = int(float(input('How many Pounds of Coffee? ')))
    except ValueError:
        print("You have not entered a valid number, please only enter a valid number.")
        exit(1)  # Non-zero exit code indicates a non-successful exit.

    if 0 <= pounds_of_coffee <= 10:
        cost = pounds_of_coffee * 12
    elif 11 <= pounds_of_coffee <= 20:
        cost = pounds_of_coffee * 10
    elif 21 <= pounds_of_coffee <= 30:
        cost = round(pounds_of_coffee * 8.75, 2)
    elif 31 <= pounds_of_coffee:
        cost = round(pounds_of_coffee * 7.50, 2)
    else:
        print("You should only be inputting positive, non-zero numbers for the number of pounds of coffee.")
        exit(1)  # Non-zero exit code indicates a non-successful exit.

    print("Your total cost is: $%d" % cost)

main()
```